# Middleman: dynamic background image?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, middleman

Some background info: 
I just started learning middleman to build my portfolio.. I don't have a programming background, so bear with me :-).

I have an index page where I list all my projects like cards, created / populated by data from a json file. This is the loop I use to create the cards for each project on the index page:

```
<div class="row">
  <% data.projects.projects.each do |project| %>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>
        <%= project.title %>
      </h2>
      <div>
        <%= link_to 'View project', project.path, relative: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is the json file from which I set the project title and url:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {"title": "One",
         "path": "/one.html"
       },
        {"title":"Two",
         "path": "/two.html"
       },
       {"title":"Three",
        "path": "/three.html"
      }
    ]
}
```

So far, so good.

Now what I want to do is to set a (unique) background image for each card, and I'm not quite sure how to do it. As I see it, there are two approaches I could take:

**1. Create the CSS rules for each card and set the class in the loop  from json:**

`bg-img-1 { background-image: url("img1.jpg"); }`

`bg-img-2 { background-image: url("img2.jpg"); }`

`bg-img-3 { background-image: url("img3.jpg"); }`

and add `{ "bg-img": "bg-img-x" }` in each project in the json file.

and then in my card creating loop add the 'bg-img' to the class of each card.

**2. Set an inline style on the div, and inject the img path from the json file:**

`<div class="card" style="background: url(<%= data.project.img %>)"> </div>`

However, neither of these solutions seem elegant / optimal?
With solution #1 making a change becomes tedious as I would have to make changes in several places, the CSS & json file.

Solution #2 doesn't have that issue, but I'm not a fan of inline styling / having styling saved in separate places.

So is there another way of doing this? Or do I have to pick one of these and deal with the pro's & cons of each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution #2 is completely fine and often used. inlining style for the background is a standard practice